# Reading "The Judging Eye" by R Scott Bakker without reading "The Prince of Nothing" series

Tags: suggested-order

A few months ago I was given a copy of *The Judging Eye*. It's been a great book, but it was obvious right away that I had a lot to catch up on. At the end of the book was a quick 6 page review which helped a lot.

So my question would be for anyone who has read *The Prince of Nothing* series and *The Judging Eye* and can let me know if I am missing much. Does *The Judging Eye* stand on it's own with a quick update about the previous books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I do not think that you should read *The Judging Eye* without reading the *The Prince of Nothing* series. Although many things are explained at the beginning of *The Judging Eye*, but I don't think you will get a feel for the characters if you start reading it straight away. Take the time to read *The Prince of Nothing* series, they are a great read. Also, I would like to point out that *The Prince of Nothing* ends in a good manner, so reading it would bring you more pleasure than reading the first book of the unfinished series.

Comment: That is what I figured. The first 50 pages were kinda rough. Unfortunately I am already 3/4 of the way through The Judging Eye, but let this question stand for future generations to not repeat my mistake.